"Knocking it out of the park" sports metaphor American English vs British English?
I came across the phrase Knocking it out of the park in US when an American colleague used it(I am sure I would have heard it on TV before, but never really noticed); I think it is a sports metaphor (Baseball, homerun).
Recently, one of my British friends used it, which I found very interesting. Could it refer to cricket as well?
Basically, Is it common for a British person to use American sport (baseball) metaphor?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Probably worth mentioning, as no one else seems to have done so... in baseball, "knocking it out of the park" means (at least) hitting the ball over the fence, resulting in an automatic home run. As an idiom, it means roughly "a wild success". There may be an implication of hitting the ball entirely out of a stadium, which would obviously be more difficult than merely clearing the back fence, hence magnifying the degree of success.

@Matthew Great Point. Especially the green monster! :)

There are equivalent analogies from British sports, for example:

hit (or knocked) it for six (cricket)
played a blinder (rugby)

These two would be interchangeable with the chiefly American "knocked it out of the park" in a sentence, and there are also other sporting analogies that mean similar but which would be phrased differently, such as "back of the net" (from association football).
However, it isn't at all surprising that your British friend used the baseball analogy. Thanks to the wide reach of American English and culture in TV and movies, most British people are very aware of US idoms including the saying "knocked it out of the park". We regularly use terms from baseball such as "ballpark figure", and "three strikes and you're out". Most surprising (to me, at least) is the phenomenon of British people using the expression "period!" at the end of sentences to emphasise completeness. British people call the punctuation mark "a full stop", and for as long as I have been alive British people would use "full stop" in the same way, but it seems that a new generation of British natives watching American TV and movies has picked up on "period" as if it is a completely different saying.

I question the assertion that 'most' British people are 'very' aware of the saying. If I heard it I would probably guess that it meant something similar to 'knocked it for six'.

@KateBunting Maybe I've watched more Hollywood movies than you, but I feel confident that if I used terms like "home run", "ballpark figure", or "three strikes and you're out" with my fellow Brits, they'd all know exactly what I meant.

@Astralbee - Your confidence may be a little misplaced. For a test, I just looked up 'home run', and found that I hadn't correctly understood what it means; I thought it was something like being in the home stretch. I consider myself very far from being an ignoramus in these matters. The others I am OK with.

@Astralbee I could still be wrong. I am from India. For character 'z', we used to call it 'zed' in school, but later it became 'zee'; Now, it looks like it is Br. English vs Am. English. Same with pronounciation of 'hour'. My american friend corrected my pronouncation of hour in US (california); Now, it looks I was pronouncing it in British way. It is really comical. :)

@MichaelHarvey Perhaps the kind of people who spend their day helping others with their English online for free are not representative of the broader population? But either way, the OP's British friend was clearly familiar with the term, and the OP themselves both knew it and recognised that it was chiefly American. I don't find that at all surprising.

@eric I thought your question was great and exactly the kind of thing this site is here for. You can research a phrase on the internet and you'll find resources from whichever dialect of English it predominantly resides in, but only native speakers can confirm if it is recognised beyond the original dialect or not. And it is, along with lots of other Americanisms. The fact that some comments are saying they don't know this one, or that one, is somewhat moot - you've either heard an idiom or you haven't, and once you've heard something there is the tendency to begin using it!

@Eric - as far I know, Americans and British people mostly pronounce 'hour' the same way (i.e. the 'h' is silent, and the 'r' may or may not be rhotic). Could you explain?

@Astralbee -  once you've heard something there is the tendency to begin using it! Indeed! I remember an article in the Guardian around 1974 in which an occasional commentator on English language language issues noted, as surprising and novel, an English High Court judge using 'no way' when speaking to the court.

@MichaelHarvey I probably won't be able to explain the difference. I just tried google searching for pronunciation, but did not find any supporting links. Interestingly, that was the first conversation I had with him (or any american friend for that matter). We used to have Disney hour in the 90s on TV in India, so I always used the pronounciation the TV show used. My American friend was so confused during the conversation; Eventually, he understood and corrected me.

@Eric - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/hour gives sound links, which give a UK non-rhotic (silent 'r') pronunciation and a US rhotic one (final 'r' is heard). However, there are US non-rhotic regions (notably New England and New York), and UK English rhotic ones (mainly the West of England).

It is not unheard of for Americans to say "full stop" at the end of a sentence to emphasize completeness. We don't see as much British media as people in Britain see American, but it's not zero. And British expressions make you sound much more worldly.

As a Brit who spends a lot of time talking to Americans, I'm pretty sure the British have a higher average awareness of American metaphors and idioms than vice-versa.

@JohnDallman absolutely. I was explaining to an American friend that we are aware of their dialect through TV and movies, and as an example I mentioned that most of us would know they call the boot and bonnet of a car the "trunk" and "hood" respectively. He looked absolutely horrified and said "your cars have boots and bonnets???"

"Out of the park" is instantly recognisable as American.  I don't know of any British sport (except perhaps imports such as skateboarding) that calls its field a "park".  But I'll sit here and wait for the examples to flood in...

@TobySpeight I can't think of any sports where 'park' is part of the terminology, yet lots of football grounds are called parks, like Goodison Park and St James' Park. British and American sports share ancestry, they diverged at different points, but for all the differences there is vestigial evidence they were once the same thing

@TobySpeight and while less common than it used to be, British Football commentators have been known to say a particular player "is all over the park" or a team doing badly has been "played off the park". It is after all where most of us started playing football as children (Jumpers for goal posts? Isn't it? Mmmm? You know! Enduring image!)

I can confirm as a BrE speaker that "knocked it out of the park" would have been very puzzling 30 years ago. Now it's an accepted idiom, though I doubt many BrE speakers even think about where it came from (baseball is not widely known).

Baseball is played on a baseball field. The park is the whole complex -- the surrounding spectator seating and all that business. Knocking it out of the park is more than a home run, it means you actually hit it over the bleachers and entirely out of the viewing area.

@JohnDallman yet British expressions enter US English, even with many Americans probably being unaware of where they came from.  Examples that have entered the language include, in addition to "full stop" (which many Americans probably have no idea refers to punctuation), we have "go missing" for "disappear" and "queue" for "line."

@MarkFoskey but most of those Americans saying "full stop" have no idea that some people use that phrase as the name of the little dot at the end of a sentence.

@TobySpeight see Darth Pseudonym's comment above.  "Park" includes the places where the spectators sit or stand; the "field" is the ground inside the fence.  A home run may be hit into the bleachers; it is only if the ball leaves the entire stadium that it is "out of the park."

It's an import
US culture is ubiquitous so American idioms are imported even into non-baseball playing cultures.
Non-American versions of English understand and use some American baseballisms such as:

Knocked it out of the park
Hit a home run
Play hardball
Left field
Step up to the plate
A curveball
Touch base
Go to bat for
Strike out
Ballpark
Bottom of the ninth
Out of one's league
etc.

We also use cricket idioms, but we don't get a Wikipedia page.

Now that you mention it, what is so special about left field? as opposed to center field, and right field?

Because the left field is behind a runner running for home. Therefore a ball that comes from out of left field is unseen.

Leagues are common in other sports, especially football (used in the global sense), right?

Are there any equivalents the other way around? As an American, I’m stumped, caught out, bowled over. It’s a sticky wicket.

@Davislor Best one is LBW. :) Also, "spin" both political and cricket wise!

I (British) have no idea what "Bottom of the ninth" means, so probably use that with some caution outside the US. "Bases" exist in rounders and in other more informal games, so that transfers seamlessly.

@FrancisDavey If I may, Baseball game has 9 innings (like cricket's 50 overs); Each inning in baseball, both teams go to bat.  There is top, and there is bottom; Away team batting is top, and home team batting is bottom. So, bottom of the 9th is effectively the last inning of the game like cricket's last over (unless it goes in extra innings due to a tie).

@Davislor, it's not clear that "bowled over" is from cricket.  I'd guess that it's more likely from the game of skittles (in fact, it's often affixed "like ninepins", which lends credence to that idea).

@Eric that is really interesting, in so far as it goes, but what does the expression mean? If someone used it in a sentence, what would they be implying?

@FrancisDavey If I have to guess, i would say it would imply "crunch time", which is a term American sports writers use all the time; American Football and Basketball have late 4th quarter as crunch time, and Baseball could have 9th inning as "crunch time" where you can have sudden-death (football/soccer penalties) like situation called walk-off. In-summary, Bottom...9th could just mean high-stakes situation.  I am obv. non-native English speaker.

@Eric You got it. (Native speaker in the U.S.) Although I’d say an inning in baseball is even more similar to an innings in cricket. The main difference is baseball calling both teams’ turn at bat one inning, versus cricket calling each team’s turn an innings, and of course the different rules for how innings end.

@Eric cricket has 3 forms, one of which has 50 overs for each team. Another has 20 each and the third is played over 5 days with no set number of overs (450 total is about average).

@FrancisDavey Baseball has 9 innings (excluding extra tie breaking innings), with each team taking a turn at bat. Because the scoresheet has a line at the top and the bottom to record the scores, they’re called the top and bottom of the ‘n’. The bottom of the 9th is only played if the game is tied or the at bat team is behind - if they are ahead when the top of the 9th ends, they have already won. In this situation the batting team has to exceed the score of the fielding team  to win the game. So it’s a do or die situation.

What Dale M said. Or, in fewer words, "bottom of the ninth" is your last chance to accomplish whatever you're trying to accomplish.

@WeiwenNg baseball depends heavily on a system where players move fairly frequently between related teams in the major leagues and the minor leagues, depending on their performance, injuries, and so on (unlike in the system of promotion and relegation that prevails in many European sports, notably football, where entire teams move up or down from one season to the next).
